# How can I remove all white parts from an image in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have this image in Photoshop below, and I am trying to figure out a way to get rid of all of the white parts of this image and replace with the same blue color that is there.

I have tried:

- Hue / Saturation
- Replace Color Tool

and neither seems to give me what I want.

Is there any way to replace the white streaks in this image with the blue color?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a few ways to go about this and you will have to experiment to see what provides the best solution:

- Select > Color Range: Use the eyedropper and select white. Then adjust the fuzziness to include only the white and nothing else. This may or may not work depending on how well it reads the colors. Once that is done it will select everything **BUT** the white. You can hit CTRL (or CMD) - Shift - I  to invert the selection.
- Try that magic wand as mentioned here, this may or may not work well, I have not always had good luck with this tool.
- This is a bit tedious but may provide the best results. Manually select the white and cut it out by hand. To do this go into Quick Mask Mode (This is the icon at the very bottom of the tools menu - see image below) then using a paintbrush paint the areas you want to select then once finished click the quick mask mode again and you have a selection made. Remember Black Paints and White Erases. Red by default will appear for what you are painting. Note: Red is what is NOT selected. You can always do as above and Invert your selection if needed. - Use a soft brush or adjust the selection with feather to fade the parts where white fades to color.

***EDIT***

I was looking through adjustment layers and came across selective color  Images > Adjustments > Selective Color

There was white as an options. I have not tried this adjustment layer but may be worth trying out.

Once Your selection is made (I would make it a new layer) you can attempt to colorize just that layer to the same blue or replace the layer with the blue color. There are a variety of was to do this depending on how you want this to look.

[image: Photoshop Quick Mask Mode Button]

Check out a couple of these tutorials - not sure how much they will help but you might learn something:

[The Secrets of Color Range Revealed!](http://av.adobe.com/russellbrown/ColorRangeRevealed_SM.mov)

[Masking Workflow Techniques](http://av.adobe.com/russellbrown/CS4Masking_SM.mov)

Some of the tutorials found [here](http://russellbrown.com/tips_tech.html) may be useful you can look and decide.

Answer (score 2):

The [Eliminate White](http://www.edesign.com/filters/) filter will replace white with transparency.  You may need to apply Layer > Matting > Remove White Matte after this to get the colors right.  Then, you can paint or fill in what you want on a new layer behind this one.

Answer (score 1):

The [magic wand tool](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Photoshop/11.0/WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-76f6a.html)[image] would do the trick - just make sure you have an appropriate tolerance level and deselect the contiguous option.

I would use that to select the area thats whiteish, add a new, transparent blue layer so you would keep the texture, but just tint it.

Comment: how can i select all of the white as its not continuous

Comment: - the answer and the link covers that - specifically deselect the contigious option "Contiguous Selects only adjacent areas using the same colors. Otherwise, all pixels in the entire image using the same colors are selected."

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Just colorise the whole thing. in Hue Saturation turn on colorise and set the colors.   The color ranging does not work because the low part of the streaks and the highlights of the swirls are the exact same color.

Comment: Now, where did the original blue image went?

Comment: it wasnt really blue :-) it was more cyan , this method you would not have control of the 2 areas seperatly, but I could make the above pic in any color. Leora said blue , but it could also be cyan or more cyan, or any other color.  If i hand to control both, back to hand selection, use a magnetic lasso.

Comment: But doesn't reproducement of the original color result in white again? He doesn't want the color to change.

Comment: sorry not my fault they show cyan and say blue :-) again it could be Any color. the pic demonstrates that the Whole thing was changed. not a part of it. The user can select thier original color if they so desire.  the pic does not have the transparency, it is only a demo, it is not doing it for them.

Answer (score 0):

you can remove all white from an image by simply selecting the layer from the layers panel and choosing "multiply" from the blending dropdown. this removes all white. Note- there must be a layer underneath like a different color background. Then, add a layer underneath the multiplied layer. Take your eye dropper and select a blue tone from the image. Get the brush tool and brush on the layer underneath the multiplied image until you get the desired effect.